# The entity or complex type 'CreditFacility_Web.Models.CreditFacilityModel.SavingsAccount' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq

Please I have a View making an AJAx call, the response is below

> Blockquote The entity or complex type 'CreditFacility_Web.Models.CreditFacilityModel.SavingsAccount' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

The Action Method is below.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AccountDetails1(string accountNo)
    {
        using (var db = new CreditFacilityContext())
        {

            var accDetails = db.SavingsAccounts.Where(t => t.Account_Number == accountNo).Select(s => new SavingsAccount
            {
                Firstname = s.Firstname,
                Account_Balance = s.Account_Balance,
                //rest of properties                    
            }).FirstOrDefault(); ;

            return Json(accDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your statement, there is no need for the select clause.

```
var accDetails = db.SavingsAccounts.Where(t => t.Account_Number == accountNo).FirstOrDefault();
```

This should yield the same result you are expecting from the Select clause.

Comment: Thank you. I already used C# code to do this but seeing this, I tried it out and it worked just with little modification to reference the particular model i am returning the values to.